# Meaning of particle で

Tags: grammar, particle-で

I'm a bit confused about で particle in 「微妙な具合で五感を鈍くしている」. Is it used here to separate 「微妙な具合」 from 「五感を鈍くしている」? Or does it show the way the summer atmosphere makes the senses of the speaker dull with its 'strange' condition?

> 開け放った窓から入ってくる夏の空気が、微妙な具合**で**五感を鈍くしているのかも知れない。
>
> 暑くはないが、涼しくもない、停滞しているような、それでいて流れの存在しているような。
>
> 全てが内保されて、中には何も存在しない。
>
> 矛盾こそが理論的であり、同時に混沌の中に秩序が成り立っている。

Comment: From what does your excerpt come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would translate 微妙な具合で to 'in a subtle way'.

How 'subtle' is it? What does 微妙な具合で actually mean? The following sentences explain:

> 暑くはないが、涼しくもない、停滞しているような、それでいて流れの存在しているような。
>
> 全てが内保されて、中には何も存在しない。
>
> 矛盾こそが理論的であり、同時に混沌の中に秩序が成り立っている。

で here shows a certain condition or state.

Answer (score 1):

This で clearly indicates cause (原因{げんいん}) [goo で ❶-7](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/148951/m0u/%E3%81%A7/).

> 開け放った窓から入ってくる夏の空気が、微妙な具合で五感を鈍くしているのかも知れない。

The summer atmosphere filtering in through the opened window. Under this delicate/subtle situation, his/her (five) senses (seem to) have become dull.

Comment: My translation is far from being good so if you have any comment, do not refrain from telling me.

Comment: goo で ❶-5 の意味では・・　「微妙な調子で」「微妙な具合に」に似ているような。。

Comment: Technically speaking, both interpretations are possible. But considering how comma is used, it's more likely the ❶-5.

Comment: @choco, user4092 I agree that the ❶-5 fits better because 具合 is more similar to 状態 than to 原因. But the difference seems small in that case and I can't really see how it would change the translation. Maybe you should post an answer. However, I don't really see how the comma change the interpretation.

Comment: ❶-5 "Perhaps, summer air blowing in from the open windows is dulling his/her five senses subtly". ❶-7 "Perhaps he is letting his five senses be dull because summer air ... is subtle".